# How to get only selected colums and format it in Django from database?

Tags: django, templates

I want to only show the selected columns from the database like:

```
Select coloum1, coloum2, coloum3 from Table1;
```

I only want to show the three columns. Using `Entry.objects.all()` doesn't let me to do so. Now, after retrieving each column I get data in this format:

```
ok.py 172.16.0.161 January 07, 2013, 11:36AM January 07, 2013, 11:36AM 0 bytes
```

I want to show each element in different columns like:

```
name    host               Date                          Date
ok.py   172.16.0.161       11:36AM January 07, 2013      2013, 11:36AM 0 bytes
```

I tried using simple for loop in template:

```
{% for i in query %}
{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

This retrieve all the elements like:

```
ok.py 172.16.0.161 January 07, 2013, 11:36AM January 07, 2013, 11:36AM 0 bytes
hello.py 172.16.0.161 January 07, 2013, 11:36AM January 07, 2013, 11:36AM 0 bytes
```

How can I show them to user in different columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for this.

Answer (score 0):

if *query* is a queryset, then the variable *i* is an object.

you can get the object attributes like normally with *object.attribute* syntax (that is, *i.name*, *i.host*, etc.)

make a regular html  out of the attributes you pull out of the loop.

You can perform a raw sql query like the following example:
first_person = Person.objects.raw('SELECT name, address from myapp_person')
for some model Person

You should definitely checkout the django documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Entry.objects.values('field1','field2','field3')` which will return a list dictionary i.e `[{'field1':value1,'field2':value2,'field3':value3},..]`

Or alternatively you could use `Entry.objects.values_list('field1','field2','field3')` which will return a list of tuples of values i.e `[(value1,value2,value3),..]`. In case you are trying to get just one field from the database this can work `Entry.objects.values_list('field1',flat=True)` the flat parameter will return a list of values instead of list of tuples of values i.e [value1a,value1b,value1c]